# Adding web sockets support to spring data rest events

Tags: websocket, spring-data-rest

I have spring data rest repositories with the default post and update and delete.
I have also implemented an Event handler, now how can I add Web sockets to the event handlers?

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
@Service
public class UserEventHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserEventHandler.class);

   @Autowired
   private SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender;

   @HandleAfterCreate
   public void handleBeforeCreate(User u) {
   }

}

// Repository class
@Transactional
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users", collectionResourceRel = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {

}
```

Comment: Can you add some source code please?

Comment: I have added my repository and event class how then can I add web sockets